# How to uninstall PostgreSql user on Mac Monterey

Tags: mac, sql, postgresql

I already deleted pgadmin 4 and the PostgreSQL apps and I don't know why the PostgreSQL user profile is listed on my task bar. I checked the official "System Preferences", and I don't see any other users listed.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: macOS doesn't have a task bar. Are you saying there's a PostgreSQL user listed in your list of users on the Fast User Switching Menu Extra in the menu bar? If so, go into System Preferences > Users & Groups and delete that user account.